# How do I add controlled scrolling in Android views

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to scroll a webview based on volume click button
I added following code first,

```
    myWebView.scrollBy(0, 250);
```

this does scroll but then the scrolling is not smooth,
view quickly alters, which is annoying.
I tried adding a loop and a time delay, something like this

```
for(int i=-250;i<250;i++)
{
Thread.sleep(Math.abs(i/20));
myWebView.scroll(0,1)
}
```

For some strange reason this is not smooth either, the program waits for some delay and scrolling happens after that and that also is not controlled.

I tried scroller

```
    Scroller sc= new Scroller(myWebView.getContext());
    sc.startScroll(0, 0, 0, 250,250);
```

this didnt even scroll.

Is there any other way to get make it work?
Or can there be some improvement in above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello did you try this method ?

```
webView.flingScroll (int vx, int vy)
```

you might find this question useful [web view smooth scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175441/1089811).

I hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed, I assumed vx is starting velocity of scroll. Thanks again